# Why does patchEntity() cut out image information? (CakePHP3)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Using the POST method `$data = $this->request->getData();` , I get the archive:

```
[
        'category_id' => '62',
        'title' => 'Name-1',
        'body' => '<p>Text</p>
    ',
        'price' => '30',
        'is_new' => '1',
        'img' => [
            'tmp_name' => 'D:\Web\OpenServer\userdata\temp\php70D9.tmp',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'name' => 'IronMan.jpg',
            'type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'size' => (int) 131830
        ]
]
```

By preparing these data for the record in the database:

```
$product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $data);
```

But the patchEntity() method cuts out all the information about the image.
I get:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Product) {

    'category_id' => (int) 62,
    'title' => 'Name-1',
    'body' => '<p>Text</p>
',
    'price' => (float) 30,
    'is_new' => (int) 1,
    'img' => '', // <--- empty :(
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        'category_id' => true,
        'title' => true,
        'body' => true,
        'price' => true,
        'img' => true,
        'is_new' => true,
        'created' => true,
        'modified' => true,
        'category' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'category_id' => true,
        'title' => true,
        'body' => true,
        'price' => true,
        'is_new' => true,
        'img' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Products'

}
```

It can be fixed? Tell me at least about. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When patching/creating an entity, the data is bein marshalled according to the respective columns data type, as you can see for other properties like `price`, which is converted from a string to a float.

Your `img` column is probably of the type string, causing the marshaller to convert the data accordingly (see [**`\Cake\Database\Type\StringType::marshal()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.5.11/src/Database/Type/StringType.php#L89)).

There are various ways to avoid that, for example using a different property name that doesn't map to an existing column, like `img_upload`, and then after moving the upload, manually set the resulting filesystem path to the `img` property and save that.

That could also be done in the `beforeMarshal` event in your `ProductsTable` class, so that the view template can continue to use the `img` property:

```
public function beforeMarshal(
    \Cake\Event\Event $event,
    \ArrayObject $data,
    \ArrayObject $options
) {
    if (isset($data['img'])) {
        $data['img_upload'] = $data['img'];
        unset($data['img']);
    }
}
```

You could also create a custom database type for the `img` column, one which doesn't marshal the data to a string, but just passes it on:

```
namespace App\Database\Type;

use Cake\Database\Type;

class FileType extends Type
{
    public function marshal($value)
    {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

You'd have to assign the filesystem path anyways though, you'd basically just avoid using a separate/temporary property.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Modifying Request Data Before Building Entities](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#modifying-request-data-before-building-entities)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Adding Custom Types](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#adding-custom-types)**

Comment: I would recommend offloading the logic to behaviors, check the awesome list for good ready to use ones: https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#files

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how much this is correct, but in the end I did the following and everything works as I need:

**In ProductsController**:

```
 public function add()
{
    $product = $this->Products->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $data = $this->request->getData();

        $product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $data);

        // If there is a picture that we checked (by the method of validationDefault, when calling patchEntity) and have already uploaded to the server in a temporary folder, then
        if($product->img_upload['name']){
            // We call the user method of processing the downloaded image
            $product = $this->_customUploadImg($product);
            // Leave only the name of the new file, adding it to the new property, with the name corresponding to the name of the table in the database
            $product->img = $product->img_upload['name'];
        }
        // Delete an unnecessary property
        unset($product->img_upload);

        if ($this->Products->save($product)) {
            // ...
        }
    // ...
}
```

**In Product.php:**

```
    class Product extends Entity{
    protected $_accessible = [
        'category_id' => true,
        'title' => true,
        'body' => true,
        'price' => true,
        'is_new' => true,
        'created' => true,
        'modified' => true,
        'category' => true,

        // 'img' => true,
        // Here we specify not 'img' as in the database table, but 'img_upload', in order for ProductsController not to delete our data file about the uploaded file when patchEntity was called.
        'img_upload' => true,
    ];
}
```

**In ProductsTable.php**:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    //...

     $validator
        ->allowEmpty('img_upload', 'create')
        ->add('img_upload', [
            'uploadError' => [
                'rule' => 'uploadError',
                'message' => 'Error loading picture'
            ],
            'mimeType' => [
                'rule' => ['mimeType', ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']],
                'message' => 'Only image files are allowed to be uploaded: JPG, PNG и GIF'
            ],
            'fileSize' => [
                'rule' => ['fileSize', '<=', '2MB'],
                'message' => 'The maximum file size should be no more than 2 MB'
            ]
        ]);

    //...
}
```

**In add.ctp**:

```
echo $this->Form->create($product, ['type' => 'file']) ?>
// ...
echo $this->Form->control('img_upload', ['type' => 'file', 'label'=>'Product photo']);
//...
```

Thanks "ndm" and "mark"!